# Conditionally Renaming Rails 3 Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

For marketing reasons, I need to update our app's routes to swap one word for another, without touching the controller names.

For example:

```
/foo_campaigns/1               becomes  /bar_campaigns/1
/foo_campaigns/accounts_foo/1  becomes  /bar_campaigns/accounts_bar/1
```

The manual way to do this is:

```
resources :foo_campaigns, :path => 'bar_campaigns' do
  match :accounts_foo, :path => 'accounts_bar'
end
```

But I am looking for a passive way to do accomplish this, where every time I create a new controller or action containing the word 'foo', the path for it will be 'bar'.

Comment: perhaps this is something you may want to do in the web server config? something like http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I'm using the Rack Rewrite gem for some redirection, but for this task I'll need to actually use native routes. I need 200 responses (not 301s) and can't allow for slower responses.

Comment: With mod_rewrite you can change the url your application sees without redirecting: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: OK - you can do this with Rack Rewrite, too. The problem is this doesn't seem to communicate this with the controllers and actions themselves, resulting in the error: "The action 'bar' could not be found for FooController'